# Converting b-string to png in Python 3.9.6

Tags: python-3.x, string, type-conversion, png

I have been trying to convert this b-string to a png image.

Here is the bytes string for a barcode received from an api. It is called Cloudmersive 1D barcode generator api.

I have tried to use base64.b64decode() and then write binary to an image file but it does not work. I also tried using BytesIO but that does not work either.
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00d\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xe5\xbc\xe2\x8d\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xb1\x8f\x0b\xfca\x05\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x01\xc7o\xa8d\x00\x00\x0c\x8aIDATx^\xed\x95\xd1\x95d\xc5\x0e\x041\x0f\x830\x07_p\xe5y\xc2SU\xce\xc4\x84\xa4Z\x18\xf6{\xe3C'\x94\xca{\xbb\xa7\x81\xc3o\x7f\x8b\xdf~;+\xd3R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083M\xdbG\xd5R\x9c\x86\xf2\xb8'\xdc\xe3\xbb\t;\xc4}\x1a\x85\x11Z\xf0"\xbe\xc3\xac\x84\x968\x12\x083\xcd\xdc\x7f\xf1M~\xfdp?\xc9\xaf\x1f\xee'\xf9\xc6\x0f\xf7\xd7\x1f\xf7\xbf\xf7\xe2\xf7?\xff\xf7\x91}R7\x87\xff\xfb\xf3\xf7\x1fU{s\xbf\xf3+\xf9\xe4\x8f\xbf\xfa\xe1c?<?\x87b\xfb\xec\xef>\xfe\x95\x1dT\xfe\x01\xff\xfa\xc3\x9d\x0f\xcek\xee\xab\xfd\xc6|\xa7\xaf\xcf>{\xb6S\xf5\xd7\xef\xcds\xfd|\xcf\xd7\xeb\x85\x1e\xaf{L\xc5\x97\xea\xcb\xf9\xc3\xbf\xfb\xf8\xd5\x0f\xfb\x1e\xff\xf6\xc3\xe9\xd5w\xf9\xf8F\xf7{\xfe\xf6\xfb\x1f\x7f\xe8\x07\xfa\xba\x9aW\xd3\xec\xa7\x9e\x7fx\xe2\xfbM\xda\x13\x9f\xcb3\xfc\xfe\xe3\xe7\xfc\x95~\x87\xff\xf8o\x1c_\xe3\xaf\xbf>>n\x7f\xb3\xce\xa3)N<\x9e\xfa\xfa\xc0\xf1\xce\xf6\x17\x7f\xf2\x19\xb6\xe3\xe7+\xbe\xff\xf8\x95\xdf\xcf?\xe2\xf3Oy\xd5\x1e|\xe7\x7f\x0e\xe7{\xbc_\xe8\x9f\xe3~\x87\xbf\xce\x0fq\xe8?\xc6\xeb\x87\xbb\xbf\xd9zi\xef\xfd\xdb_~\xbeY\xb2\xfb\xb6\x8f\xea\xfd\xbe\xdf\xf9\xe1\xfa\xe3\x1fW\xbf\xe9\x1f\xf8\xd6\xbfq\x1f\xaf<\xda\xdf\xa8\xcf\xcb\xd7\xd5\x87\x7f\xe6a'\x97\xf9-G\xed\xac?\xfc\xcb\xef\xb3J\xee\x178\xfc\xf1\xe7\xc7c\xff\xe9\xf1/\xf6\xdf\xf9\xe0\xdf~\xb8\xf9\xd9\xfd\x8d\xe7\xfa\xf9\xd9\xed\xd8\x1e;\xb8\xd9\xe8\x7f\xcf\xf8\xeb\xe6\xa7\x7f\xdd\xce\xe5\xfd\xc2\xa2\x8e\xf7\xf4\xf3\x8f\xf7/\xff\xe2?\xfdp\xeb\x8d'\xf8\xfc\xf8\xef7\x1b\xed\xef\xa9\xa5?\xa6\xab^y\xf4\x87\x7f\xb6\x9b?\xf5x\xffJ?\xe2_\xffS=\x9f\xf2\xf1\x9a\xf5g\xf9X|}\xe0?7u\xed/8[\x7f\xec\xab\xfb\xf5P\x7f\xe6\x03\x85\xfe\xf0\xef>\xaeg\x8e\xae\xfb\xe6\xbf\xfc\xcf\xe1\x1f\xbf\xee\xe5\xec\xe1\xf3\x9b\x7f\xd2\x9b_\xbdV\xd4\xd7\xff\x82O\xd7\x1f\xd6\xc9\xe1\xeb\x9d\xedk\xfe\xf7\xc7\xf7Wx\xf1\x9d\x1f\xee\x17\x0f~\xfdp?\xc9\xaf\x1f\xee\xa7\xf8\xfb\xef\xff\x03\x11\xda\xa3\xaefM\x89\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use `b64decode` or any other operation on that byte string, it's ready to write to the file as is.

```
with open(r'c:\temp\temp.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b_str)
```

It produces this:

[image]

Comment: @munjpate put your code in the question where it belongs.

Comment: I have tried to do this but once my file has been created, it shows in PyCharm "Image not Loaded" The api response is a bytes object. Here is my code. I am not able to convert bytes object to string successfully. Any recommendations? 
`with open('barcodes\\barcode.png', 'wb') as pic:
                pic.write(api_response)`

Comment: @munjpate have you verified that the file is where you expect it to be and has the proper name?  Have you tried to open it with a different application?  The picture I show in my answer is from the data string you included in the question so it works for me.

Comment: The api response that I get is considered as a string not bytes although it has the b in front of the string. `with open('barcodes\\barcode.png', 'wb') as pic:
                pic.write(api_response)` shows this error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` unless I do `api_response.encode('utf-8')` and pass the encoded value in the f.write. If I print the response and then copy it and pass it in to the code like you have, it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @munjpate your string wouldn't have a `b` in front of it unless it was already a byte string.  The things you're saying don't add up, which makes your problem unsolvable.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try to figure out more.